# Using OOP with PDO

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I am using a class that fetches information from a database and shows that information in a table, along with an edit and delete button. When I click the edit or delete button, I want to add `$_GET['id']` to the link, but I am confused on how to accomplish this.

```
public function select($tName,$from,$where=1){
    $key=[];

    $con=$this->con;
    $sql="SELECT $tName FROM $from WHERE $where";
    $data = $con->query($sql);

    $fullRec=[];
    foreach($data as $k=>$rows){
    $fullRec[]=$rows;
    }
    foreach($rows as $k=>$v){
       $key[] = $k;
    }
    //create table
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    //create one row with col name selected!!
    echo "<tr>";
    for($z=0;$z<count($key);$z+=2){
        echo "<td>".$key[$z]."</td>";
    }
    echo "<td>actions</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    //create one row for each record comes!!
    for($i=0;$i<count($fullRec);$i++){
        echo "<tr>";
        //create one table data for each record comes!!
        for($j=0;$j<count($fullRec[$i])/2;$j++){
            echo "<td>".$fullRec[$i][$j]."</td>";

        }
        echo "<td><a href=\"\">Edit</a><a href=\"?del=".$rows['id']."\">Delete</a></td>";

        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: This code isn't particularly good from an OOP programming style, you are mixing database access and presentation layers into one method of one class.

Comment: database access is in other method but i want in select method catch informations and show in table and i want have delete and edit in each row

Comment: @MahdiPartovi You should read up on [MVC](https://www.sitepoint.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-1/). You should have a controller which tells the browser exactly what you want to load and interacts with the Model. A Model is where ALL database access goes, but NOT any sort of HTML generation and nothing the user can see. The model will pull information from the database, then the controller will interact with this data to display the View. The View is the actual page the user sees. Basically, anything related to the database should be a part of the Model and nothing else.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use like this to pass the id of the record in get parameter

```
echo "<a href='your_route?del=".$rows['id']."'>DELETE</a>";
```

Comment: ok but when i click on delete link create another record in DB with null index

Comment: you must check your delete code functionality in backend

Comment: id that sent to $_GET is last id in $rows and when i delete line with id=1 send last id in table into $_GET